# GCC error when installing MySQL_python 1.2.2 (Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard)

Tags: python, mysql, gcc, mysql-python

I'm trying to install MySQL_python 1.2.2 (I specifically need this version, not the current 1.2.3) on Snow Leopard, and getting this error below.

Command to install:

```
pip install -Iv http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.2/MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar.gz/download
```

And a portion of the trace:

```
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6

/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,2,'final',0) - D__version__=1.2.2 -I/usr/local/mysql/include - I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o    build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL

In file included from _mysql.c:35:

/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:1053:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,

             from pymemcompat.h:10,

             from _mysql.c:29:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:803:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

In file included from /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql.h:47,

             from _mysql.c:40:

/usr/include/sys/types.h:92: error: duplicate ‘unsigned’

/usr/include/sys/types.h:92: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers

error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search yielded [this answer](http://justcramer.com/2007/11/05/mysqldb-on-leopard/):

> To get mysqldb working on leopard I found I had to edit _mysql.c and edit out the lines:
>
> ```
> #ifndef uint
> #define uint unsigned int
> #endif
> ```
>
> I also had to edit site.cfg and mark threadsafe to False.
>
> After doing this, I managed to get MySQLdb to install, great! Not so
>   fast, there was yet another problem:
>
> Referenced from: .../_mysql.so Reason: image not found
>
> The solution:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/ /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
> ```

Comment: For future searchers, I only needed to take the first step from this link (comment out three lines in _mysql.so).

Comment: There is actually no need to do this. Just install python-dev and libmysqlclient, then pip install MySQL-python.

Comment: @shakabra: You didn't read the first sentence of the question, did you?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, things have been redefined. I've gotten around this in the past by commenting out the offending declarations in the source of the library being build. That solution however has some obvious problems...